# Inline Styling not working when property is set dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the `elem.style` object to add inline styling to an element. Which property to change varies and therefore is set dynamically. This, however, does not work. If I e.g. change it to `elem.style.listStyleType` or any other non-dynamically set property it does work.

The property is passed as a string so I already tried to remove the quotes from the string but that does not work either. Thanks for any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="example_cnt doc_widget_cnt" onchange="docWidget(event, this, 'listStyleType')">
```

JS:

```
var docWidget = function(evt, elem, cssPropVal){
    if(evt.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
        var labelText = evt.target.parentElement.textContent;
        elem.lastElementChild.style.cssPropVal = labelText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: try `.style[cssPropVal] = whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
elem.lastElementChild.style[cssPropVal] = labelText;
```